# What would be the best translation of "things & places"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I'm looking for a good translation of "things and places", hopefully someone can help me. The context: Let's say it'll be used as a title that covers a chapter of things and places in general; things such as artwork (paintings and statues) and architecture, and places like specific cities - not necessarily connected.

Suggestions when I've tried to look this up have been *rebus et locis*, *res et loca* and *rebus et loci*.

After what I've found *loca* is used when places are connected, which in this case will not be the case. I've learned from my studies that *loci* is plural of locus, but found out that it was a bit more complicated than this. And then it is *res* vs *rebus*. I really could need help with this. What would be the best translation (or forming of the title)?

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differences you've found relate to case. Think like in English we have "he, him, his" - same word, different grammatical function.

The typical way of denoting a topic in ancient Latin (and quite often Neo-Latin) literature is with the preposition *De* (which means something akin to "concerning" or "on", like *De Rerum Natura*, "On the Nature of Things") + the words in the ablative case. For "things and places," you'd end up with something like:

> **De Rebus et Locis**

Comment: +1 for this. Still, since OP's "things" are like artwork, paintings, architecture, etc., I suggest that *operibus* might be more appropriate than *rebus*.

Comment: @MPW I wasn't sure if OP was limiting it to those sorts of things, or just giving them as examples of what things are. I would agree that *operibus* is a better fit for "works" created by people. Hopefully he can clarify.

Comment: cmw's answer is correct and excellent; however, I must say that the title "Things and Places" leaves me a little flat.  The suggested Latin answer also tends to suggest a global philosophical treatment, rather than just a semi-random list.  You might want to consider adding another word or two to peak interest more, such as "Things and Places to Visit/View" or "Things and Places to Wonder at" or "Things and Places to Compare"  The Latin for these could be "Res/Opera et Loci Visendi" or "Res/Opera et Loci Mirandi" or Res/Opera et Loci Comparandi."

Comment: @cmw : Agreed, details are scant here, so it's hard to say for sure. +1.

Comment: This answer nicely shirks the whole *loci* vs. *loca* business ;-)

Comment: @Vegawatcher I agree that narrowing it down by adding a word or two would be best if the purpose was to focus on a specific direction, in this case it is global approach (I used title and chapter as metaphors). The expression/title "Things and places" is to be seen an overarching phrase, like an umbrella, that enabling exploring many things within artwork, architecture and places (if this makes any sense). Will it then still leave you "a little flat"? Is it other expressions that might be better?

Comment: @MPW thank you, I'll keep operibus in mind.

Comment: As a chapter title, using a vague word like "things" might be okay, because it would fit within a larger context.  Maybe one chapter is entitled "People"; another, "Emotions", another "Hearth and Home,"  even so, all these are 'things" as well in one sense of the word.  "De operibus et locis" tells me you are going to say something interesting about artwork/crafts and locations.   This would not include a discussion about some purely utilitarian object or some natural object too small to be thought of as a location, but would certainly cover paintings, statutes, and architecture.